# npm private global scoped : command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, npm-install

I published a private NPM package using the [GitLab NPM Package Repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html), which needs to be scoped.

This package is supposed to add an `sspm` command available globally to work as a CLI.

When I install it from the repository using `npm install -g @{ORG}/{PACKAGE_NAME}`, it is correctly added under `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@{ORG}/{PACKAGE_NAME}` and the files seems correct, but when I run one of the following commands, the command is not found :

```sh
# zsh: command not found: sspm ​
sspm
@{ORG}/sspm
@{ORG}\/sspm
```

But if I install the package globally using the project path instead of its name, it works (even if when I install it using its name, the files are correctly downloaded)

Here is all I've tried until here

```sh
npm install -g @{ORG}/{PACKAGE_NAME}
sspm # command not found

npm uninstall -g @{ORG}/{PACKAGE_NAME}

npm install -g ./ # Installing the project from its project directory
sspm # WORKS
```

Here is my `package.json` file :

```json
{
  "name": "@{ORG}/{PACKAGE_NAME}",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "@{ORG}:registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../packages/npm/"
  },
  "bin": {
    "sspm": "./bin/main.js"
  },
  "scripts": {...},
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/..."
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/..."
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/...,
  "devDependencies": {...},
  "dependencies": {...}
}
```

### Update (2021-04-20)

Inspecting the NPM location for commands (found by running `npm bin -g`) it turns out that there is no symlink created for this package. My NPM config shows that the `bin-links` option is correctly set to true.

I also tried to publish an example public package on npmjs.com using the same `package.json` syntax, and my command was available globally after the install. When I published the same exact package on the GitLab NPM registry, the command was not found after the installation.

As a workaround, I tried to add a `scripts.postinstall` entry to my `package.json` which was supposed to create the missing symlinks for each missing `bin` entry. But it turns out that the script is not executed after the installation while the NPM documentation says that it should

So, except blaming the GitLab NPM Registry itself, I’m running out of ideas…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Resolution Thread source](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/npm-package-registry-does-not-install-correctly-global-commands/51762/3)

It seems that using GitLab NPM registry with NPM v7+ prevent the `postinstall` hook to be executed. Just downgrading NPM made the global installation from the GitLab NPM registry to execute `postinstall` script which allow to create the symlink for each `package.json.bin` entry.

To resolve the problem, we have downgraded to NPM `6.14.12` : `npm install -g npm@6.14.12`